# replacing from one column to another using r

Tags: r

I am new to `R` but have a very large file to work with.
I have a table in `R` that looks like this:

```
CHROM   POS         ID  REF ALT Sample1 Sample2
   20     1  rs1000000    G   A     1/1     0/0
   20     2  rs1000002    A   G     1/1     0/1
   20     3  rs1000004    A   G     0/0     0/0
```

I would like to look in Column 6 `Sample1` and replace the "0's" with the letter in the corresponding row in Column 4 `REF`. I want to delete the slashes and repeat this by replacing the ones in Column 6 `Sample1` with the letter in Column 5 `ALT`. I want to do this for every row in the table. This is the expected result:

```
CHROM   POS         ID  REF ALT Sample1 Sample2
   20     1  rs1000000    G   A      AA     GG
   20     2  rs1000002    A   G      GG     AG
   20     3  rs1000004    A   G      AA     AA
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to first split `Sample1` column on `/`. Check if split values are `0` then replace this value with `REF` otherwise `ALT` column's content. Finally concatenate these replaced values to have the final result.

Repeat the same process for `Sample2`.

(**Assumption** - `Sample1` & `Sample2` will always have either `0` or `1` only)

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Sample1 = paste(ifelse(strsplit(Sample1, split = '/')[[1]] == 0, REF, ALT), collapse = ""),
         Sample2 = paste(ifelse(strsplit(Sample2, split = '/')[[1]] == 0, REF, ALT), collapse = ""))
```

which gives

```
> df1
  CHROM   POS ID        REF   ALT   Sample1 Sample2
1    20     1 rs1000000 G     A     AA      GG     
2    20     2 rs1000002 A     G     GG      AG     
3    20     3 rs1000004 A     G     AA      AA
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(CHROM = c(20L, 20L, 20L), POS = 1:3, ID = c("rs1000000", 
"rs1000002", "rs1000004"), REF = c("G", "A", "A"), ALT = c("A", 
"G", "G"), Sample1 = c("1/1", "1/1", "0/0"), Sample2 = c("0/0", 
"0/1", "0/0")), .Names = c("CHROM", "POS", "ID", "REF", "ALT", 
"Sample1", "Sample2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#  CHROM POS        ID REF ALT Sample1 Sample2
#1    20   1 rs1000000   G   A     1/1     0/0
#2    20   2 rs1000002   A   G     1/1     0/1
#3    20   3 rs1000004   A   G     0/0     0/0
```